Plotting functions of x and y in ggplot2
I am trying to recreate this plot in R using ggplot2. Essentially, the problem I run into is I do not know how to plot the lines corresponding to the TAS variable. I know the function of TAS = sqrt(x*y/978), but I am not able to pass a function with both x and y arguments in stat_function. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?
Thank you very much for your time.
My code:
ggplot(df, aes(x = cc_q75,y = ss_ngene)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_function(fun = function(x,y) sqrt(x*y/978)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 200) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.2)+
  theme_minimal()

Edit: Added a sample of my input
head(df, n = 20)
cc_q75 ss_ngene
 <num>    <int>
0.27      167
0.31      158
0.57      310
0.48      172
0.63      220
0.21      135
0.28      136
0.48      276
0.59      319
0.42      251
0.34      162
0.27       95
0.71      429
0.29      104
0.57      409
0.72      537
0.57      429
0.59      400
0.40      235
0.37      146


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You'll likely need to do some algebra to transform your equation to a proper function with an x input and y output.

Post the results of dput(df). For most questions, ALL the data isn't required, just enough to show the structure and run the code.

Thank you for your comments. I added a sample of my df.

If you use dput(head(df, n = 20)) then we don't have to type it all in...

Each TAS line is defined by TAS = sqrt(x*y/978) For example the 0.2 line is defined by 0.2 = sqrt(x*y/978). After some arithmetic you can put this in the form of y = f(x) for use in geom_function(). Then you can make a list of geom_function()s for each TAS line to add to the plot.
The trickier part, in my opinion, is developing the transform for the secondary axis. However, this is simplified because TAS is evaluated at x = 1.
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- read_delim(
'cc_q75      ss_ngene
0.27      167
0.31      158
0.57      310
0.48      172
0.63      220
0.21      135
0.28      136
0.48      276
0.59      319
0.42      251
0.34      162
0.27      95
0.71      429
0.29      104
0.57      409
0.72      537
0.57      429
0.59      400
0.40      235
0.37      146', 
delim = "      "
)

tas_values <- seq(0.2, 0.8, 0.2)

geom_tas <- function(tas) {
  map(
    tas, 
    ~ geom_function(
      fun = function(x) (978 * .x^2) / x, 
      color = "blue", 
      linetype = "dashed"
    )
  )
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = cc_q75, y = ss_ngene)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_tas(tas_values) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 200) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.2) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 1000), 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ sqrt(. / 978), "TAS", breaks = tas_values)
  )
#> Warning in sqrt(./978): NaNs produced


Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0
Note, the transform is producing NaNs for negative y values, but this can be safely ignored.
